# How can I get a code review by other developers

Tags: review

As a beginner JavaScript developer, I have the following problem.

I face a JS challenge or task, I fix it, but I'm not sure if my approach is the right one.
Yes, it works, but I know that there must be a better way to achieve the same.

**Now my question is:**

Is there any way, that you could publish your code on a platform (maybe GitHub) and ask other developers to review it?

How can I get code reviews by other developers? Do you know any way?

Thanks

Comment: Um, [codereview.se]? Be sure to read their guidelines very carefully and understand them thoroughly before posting there, though.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot find their guidelines.

Comment: As with all [se] sites, you can find them in the site's [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com\help)

Answer (score 3):

You can head to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for this exact purpose.